# Delete temporary table with 'ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS' option in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I use jdbc and oracle db. How can i create global temporary table with option `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, and then drop that table with another statement?
My code example shown in below.

```
queryOfStatement1 = "CREATE GLOBAL TEMORARY TABLE MY_TABLE (ID VARCHAR(20 BYTE), NAME VARCHAR(20 BYTE)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS";
statement1.execute();
statement1.commit();
queryOfStatement2 = "DROP TABLE MY_TABLE";
statement2.execute();
statement2.commit();
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to use Global Temporary Tables.  They are different from Temporary Tables in T-SQL, which are more like in-memory collections..

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Oracle official documentation: "Temporary tables are useful in applications where a result set is to be buffered (temporarily persisted). During the session, the itinerary data is private. At the end of the session, the optional itineraries are dropped."

You can't alter table definition in the same session either, you must disconnect and connect in order to alter or drop your temporary table.

In your example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "Z_TEST"
SQL>


SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TABLE
  2  (
  3    ID VARCHAR(20 BYTE),
  4    NAME VARCHAR(20 BYTE)
  5  )
  6  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_table values ('this is id','this name') ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL>

/* alter table example */

SQL>alter table
    my_table
    add
   (col3 varchar2(100));

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use

SQL> drop table my_table ;
drop table my_table
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

SQL>

SQL> show user
USER is "Z_TEST"
SQL> select * from my_table ;

ID                   NAME
-------------------- --------------------
this is id           this name

SQL>

/* DISCONNECT SESSION AND CONNECT AGAIN */
SQL> conn z_test/welcome1
Connected.

SQL> show user
USER is "Z_TEST"
SQL> select * from my_table ;

no rows selected

SQL>

SQL>  alter table
    my_table
    add
   (col3 varchar2(100)) ;  


Table altered.

SQL>

SQL> drop table my_table ;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

It's important to note that when you disconnect/connect you will find and "empty table", as I stated in the beginning: "At the end of the session, the optional itineraries are dropped.". Your application design must consider this expected behavior.

Comment: "Temporary tables exist only in memory".  Not true.  The contents of a Global Temporary Table is written to - and read from - a temporary tablespace, that is, to disk.  This can be a substantial overhead, and is the main reason why we should only use a GTT when there is no better option.